# Access Settings in Start Script of Safari Extension

Tags: javascript, safari, safari-extension

I'm working on a Safari extension now, but I haven't been able to find a way to access any of the extension's settings from within the start script. I can access them just fine from the end script by getting them from messages to the global.html file. However, when I try that in the start script, I never seem to get a response back from global.html. Does anyone know a solution to this? Or am I just overlooking something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a start script, you are injecting it and accessing that page's DOM. Rather than making calls against the `SafariExtension` class, you'll want to make them against the `SafariContentExtension` class. This is a relatively minor difference, but it makes *all* the difference when you are accessing extension functionality from an injected script rather than a global page.

EDIT: Since answering this question a couple of days ago, I've begun working on adding a custom settings page to my own Safari extension. It appears that you can only access the `baseURI` variable of your extension using the `SafariContentExtension` class. Apparently Apple won't give that class the same access as the full `SafariExtension` one.